# mysqldump exports only one table

Tags: innodb, mysql

I was using mysqldump to export the database, like this:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword my_database > c:\temp\my_database.sql
```

Somehow, it only exports one table. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which table? only first?

Comment: Is that single exported table is also InnoDB?

Comment: Try it with the -B switch: `mysqldump -u root -ppassword -B my_database`

Comment: musqldump -u root -p  dbname tablename > tablename.sql

Answer (score 127, accepted):

try this.
There are in general three ways to use mysqldump—

in order to dump a set of one or more tables,

```
shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

a set of one or more complete databases

```
shell> mysqldump [options] --databases db_name ...
```

or an entire MySQL server—as shown here:

```
shell> mysqldump [options] --all-databases
```

Comment: Thanks, what helped me eventually was the 3rd option: mysqldump [options] --all-databases

Comment: > mysqldump -u remoteuser -p -h remote_ip db_name tbl_name > tbl_name_remote.sql  > mysql -u localuser -p db_name < tbl_name_remote.sql

Comment: @ManelPNavarro, let me know the full command and mysql server version

Comment: why is this upvoted at all ? it's lightyears from answering the question

Comment: An example would have been great. Just like [ANSWER BELOW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157438/nids-barthwal)

Answer (score 56):

Quoting this link:
http://steveswanson.wordpress.com/2009/04/21/exporting-and-importing-an-individual-mysql-table/

- Exporting the Table

To export the table run the following command from the command line:

```
mysqldump -p --user=username dbname tableName > tableName.sql
```

This will export the tableName to the file tableName.sql.

- Importing the Table

To import the table run the following command from the command line:

```
mysql -u username -p -D dbname < tableName.sql
```

The path to the tableName.sql needs to be prepended with the absolute path to that file. At this point the table will be imported into the DB.

Comment: where do you export it?

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil In a file, looking in this snipper, the file will be tableName.sql

Answer (score 28):

Here I am going to export 3 tables from database named myDB in an sql file named table.sql

```
mysqldump -u root -p myDB table1 table2 table3 > table.sql
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

In case you encounter an error like this

> mysqldump: 1044 Access denied when using LOCK TABLES

A quick workaround is to pass the `–-single-transaction` option to `mysqldump`.

So your command will be like this.

`mysqldump --single-transaction -u user -p DBNAME > backup.sql`

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked well. All tables from the database was backed up in the `.sql` file successfully.

```
mysqldump.exe -e --databases -u<db name> -p<Password> -h<host name> <database name> --skip-lock-tables --column-statistics=0 > C:\test.sql
```